# Jagged edges using CSS not rendering in IE properly

Tags: css

I am trying to add a sawtooth effect like this at the bottom of my webpage.

http://d.pr/i/GpOb

I have managed to find some code that works nicely in all browsers with the exception of internet explorer where I get the following result.

http://d.pr/i/VdLe

Unfortunately avoiding internet explorer is not an option and I am at the limit of my knowledge on how to fix this.

this is the code I am using in the CSS file.

```
            #footer {
            position:relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 280px;
            margin-top:5px;
            background-color: #ab1919 ;
            z-index:1;
            border-bottom: 10px ridge #ab1919 ;
            }


            #footer:before {

            content: " ";
            display:block;
            position: relative;
            top:0px;left:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:36px;
                background: linear-gradient(#fff 0%, transparent 0%), linear-gradient(135deg, #ab1919 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #ab1919 linear-gradient(45deg, #ab1919 33.33%, #fff 33.33%) 0 0%;
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, transparent 0%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #ab1919 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #ab1919 -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #ab1919 33.33%, #fff 33.33%) 0 0%;
                background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, transparent 0%), -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #ab1919 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #ab1919 -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #ab1919 33.33%, #fff.33%) 0 0%;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, transparent 0%), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #ab1919 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #ab1919 -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #ab1919 33.33%, #fff   33.33%) 0 0%;
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                background-size: 0px 100%, 9px 27px, 9px 27px;
            }
```

If anyone can help with this issue I will be eternally grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of IE? Linear gradients and `:after` is only supported by more recent versions of IE.

Comment: it has to be able to work with all versions because its for a school website. So I have no control over which browsers access it.

Comment: is there anyway of saying if ie version < 9 don't include this effect?

Comment: All versions probably means IE6+, in that case forget about `:before`, `:after`, `linear-gradient`, `background-size` etc..

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with images DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/YyyP9/

```
body, html {
    height:100%; background:url(http://www.hscripts.com/freeimages/icons/symbols/shapes/triangle/triangle-image8.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:bottom;
}
```

Comment: +1, Definitely do this with images.  The pattern would be tiny, and you can even toss it into the CSS if the extra request bothers you.